# What are the cheapest ways to get from East Asia to Australia?

Tags: japan, australia, southeast-asia, south-korea, east-asia

I have a return ticket that gets me from Turkey to Korea to Australia but it cannot be extended beyond the end of May.

I'm thinking of forfeiting or refunding some leg(s) of my ticket but as my savings are getting low and getting to Australia is usually not cheap I'm worried about how to ultimately get back to Australia when my funds have dwindled and I want to earn an Aussie wage again.

I know that in most of Asia and connecting Asia to the world the cheapest option is to fly Air Asia, but I also know that some important missing links in the network have been Australia, Korea, and Japan. I've also heard that both Korea and Japan have lacked low-cost carriers comparable to Ryanair and Easyjet, especially ones with international connections. I also know that there is at least the option of flying JetStar between Japan and Australia pretty cheaply.

So my questions is:

**Is the Japan-Australia connection via JetStar the cheapest way to get from East Asia to Australia or are there now options with Air Asia or other carriers I don't know?**

I'm happy to fly from Korea, Japan, or Somewhere in Southeast Asia that might be well connected to both, such as Bali or Bangkok.

(I appreciate that prices will vary depending on dates but as I don't have an idea of dates in advance since it depends on my money I'm looking for the generally cheapest routes and airlines that I should consider.)

Comment: Where in Aus would make a difference...

Comment: For me it wouldn't matter. I'm a citizen so I can work anywhere or hitchhike to Sydney for free once I'm on the continent.

Comment: I was hoping to see a boat option of some sort. Is air travel the only way?

Comment: @axsvl77: There's definitely nothing scheduled by boat. There may be cruises sometimes but not cheap. Working as crew on a yacht etc is possible but apparently tricky to find but probably depends on what skills you have.

Answer (score 6):

Jetstar Bali to Perth is around 70.4 USD/52 Euro (plus hidden cost).

Since I think Denpasar Bali International Airport is one of the nearest international Airport from Australia, I believe this price is the cheapest.[image]

Alternatively you can try AirAsia Bali to Perth, it cost around 77 USD at the same time(15 March)

Answer (score 5):

You can fly from Singapore to Perth with [Tiger Airways](http://tigerairways.com/sg/en/) from 130 Euros (plus some hidden costs), I am not sure whether that is cheap compared to other options and you may also don't want to go to WA, but it is an option.

Answer (score 4):

Air Asia flies from Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia to Melbourne, Sydney and the Gold Coast, and is usually the cheapest way to fly into Oz by a long shot.  They also connect KL to Japan and Korea.  (Usual LCC disclaimers apply: book well in advance and be prepared to fly at awkward times.)

Jetstar also flies from Singapore to Darwin and Melbourne.

Comment: This could be the best answer if it included rough prices.

Comment: Lazy much?  Air Asia's long-haul tickets start from RM99, and there's a big promo starting tomorrow (15 Feb).  Usually you'd be looking at A$150-200 though for KUL-MEL, although the full 'regular' price is twice that.  Jetstar also does fares sometimes for $99, but you're probably too late for those.  There's a promo for MEL-SIN for A$329 in Feb-Mar right now, but that sale fare is only in the 'wrong' direction.

Comment: Don't forget that Stack Exchange is less about helping the OP than about persisting answers for everybody else with a similar question in the future that arrives via search engines...

Comment: Airline prices, especially for LCCs, are so volatile that there's not much point in writing down today's prices for tomorrow's sake.

Comment: That;s true to an extent, but often it's more like indicated in Rudy's answer too.